# php gnupg decrypt exists with "decrypt failed"

Tags: php, encryption, public-key-encryption, gnupg, pgp

I try to encrypt and decrypt a string with php gnupg. The encryption work well. It could be decrypted via shell.

When I try to decrypt the string with gnupg_decrypt it terminates with a simple "decrypt failed".

I tried to regenerate the keys with different methods but the result is the same.

The code seems to import only the public key but the private key isn't imported.

- PHP-Version: 7.2.5
- GPGme Version: 1.10.0
- Extension Version: 1.4.0
- gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.4
  --libgcrypt 1.8.1

How could I decrypt the text?

The folowing code is used to decrypt the message:

```
// initialize PGP
putenv("GNUPGHOME=".__DIR__."/.gnupg");
$oPgp = new gnupg();
var_dump($oPgp->keyinfo(''));

// get encrypted Message
$sEncryptedText = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/msg.txt');

// import Key
$mInfo = $oPgp->import($sPrivateKey);

// show infos
echo "<br><br> Private-Key: <br> ";
var_dump($mInfo);

echo "<br><br>was Key added?<br>";
var_dump($oPgp->adddecryptkey($mInfo['fingerprint'], 'here is the correct password'));

echo 'Decrypted:<br>';
var_dump( $oPgp->decrypt($sEncryptedText));

echo 'Errors:<br>';
var_dump($oPgp->geterror());

$oPgp->cleardecryptkeys();

var_dump($oPgp->keyinfo(''));
```

The output is the flollowing:

```
/var/www/html/encrypt_test/encrypt.php:73: array (size=0)
empty


Private-Key: 
/var/www/html/encrypt_test/encrypt.php:83:
array (size=9)
  'imported' => int 1
  'unchanged' => int 0
  'newuserids' => int 0
  'newsubkeys' => int 0
  'secretimported' => int 1
  'secretunchanged' => int 0
  'newsignatures' => int 0
  'skippedkeys' => int 0
  'fingerprint' => string 'fingerprint1' (length=40)


was Key added?
/var/www/html/encrypt_test/encrypt.php:86:boolean true
Decrypted:
/var/www/html/encrypt_test/encrypt.php:89:boolean false
Errors:
/var/www/html/encrypt_test/encrypt.php:92:string 'decrypt failed' (length=14)
/var/www/html/encrypt_test/encrypt.php:96:
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      'disabled' => boolean false
      'expired' => boolean false
      'revoked' => boolean false
      'is_secret' => boolean false
      'can_sign' => boolean true
      'can_encrypt' => boolean true
      'uids' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=6)
              'name' => string 'name' (length=x)
              'comment' => string 'comment' (length=x)
              'email' => string 'email' (length=x)
              'uid' => string 'uid' (length=x)
              'revoked' => boolean false
              'invalid' => boolean false
      'subkeys' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=11)
              'fingerprint' => string 'fingerprint1' (length=X)
              'keyid' => string 'id1' (length=X)
              'timestamp' => int 1234
              'expires' => int 0
              'is_secret' => boolean false
              'invalid' => boolean false
              'can_encrypt' => boolean false
              'can_sign' => boolean true
              'disabled' => boolean false
              'expired' => boolean false
              'revoked' => boolean false
          1 => 
            array (size=11)
              'fingerprint' => string 'fingerprint2' (length=x)
              'keyid' => string 'keyid2' (length=x)
              'timestamp' => int 1234
              'expires' => int 0
              'is_secret' => boolean false
              'invalid' => boolean false
              'can_encrypt' => boolean true
              'can_sign' => boolean false
              'disabled' => boolean false
              'expired' => boolean false
              'revoked' => boolean false
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the Solution:
In GPG version > 2.0.0 you can't pass a Password to the private key. This is restricted, cause of security reasons. The password shouldn't pass readable to the program.

It could be fixed in two ways:

One way is to use a Key without a Password. Then you can use the Method without a Password.

The other way is to allow unattended processing. You can see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#Unattended_passphrase) how to do that.